# How can I access Mathematica on a more powerful machine remotely?

Tags: code

I have Mathematica installed on my machine. My code is taking a long time. It could be owing to my machine strength. Is there a way to run my code remotely on a cloud?

Comment: use cloud mathematica? https://www.wolframcloud.com/

Comment: Remote Batch Jobs? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RemoteBatchJobs.html

Comment: It could be because of an infinite loop or other nonterminating computation. In that case, there would be no point running it on any other platform. Also, in the case that it does terminate but take a long time, the end result may be practically useless. Have you tried to exclude these possibilities?